# SQL server Data Tools- can not browse the deployed cube

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, ssas, business-intelligence

I'm trying to browse the deployed cube, but it doesn't work. I have this error: `"Element "return" was not found. Line 5, position 2"`. I've made the connection with database and it worked (I saw that when I created dimensions and cubes). Also the deployment completed successfully. How can I fix this problem?

Advanced Information:

> Program Location:    at System.Xml.XmlReader.ReadStartElement(String
>   name)    at
>   Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaReader.ReadStartElement(String
>   name)    at
>   Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.SupportsProperty(String
>   propName)    at
>   Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.Connect(ConnectionInfo
>   connectionInfo, Boolean beginSession)    at
>   Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.XmlaClientProvider.Connect(Boolean
>   toIXMLA)    at
>   Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.XmlaClientProvider.Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.IXmlaClientProviderEx.ConnectIXmla()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.ConnectToIXMLA(Boolean
>   createSession)    at
>   Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.Open()    at
>   Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Browse.ConnectionsManagerBase.Connect()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Browse.DimensionBrowser.ConnectionManager.Connect()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Browse.DimensionBrowser.EstablishConnection()
>   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Browse.DimensionBrowser..ctor(String
>   nameOfDimension, Object dimensionObject, IServiceProvider
>   iserviceProvider, DesignerPageRelevantData designerPageRelevantData,
>   UserContextData securityContextData)    at
>   Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Browse.DimensionBrowserHostControl.CreateBrowser()
>   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Browse.BrowserHostControl.LoadBrowser()

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue - it seems to have something to do with the connection timing out. Changing the connection time-out value in the connection options to a higher value (30, 60, etc) fixed the issue.